# Installshield Limited Edition 2013 licencing on TFS 2012 build server

Tags: tfs, installshield, build-server, installshield-2013

I am trying to build a project with build server and it keeps giving me the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets (108): -7159: The product license has expired or has not yet been initialized.
```

I have added the account used by Build in the build collection administrator group and project collection administrator group. I also activated installshield both through Visual Studio (creating new setup project) and then going in this location 
`c$\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2013LE\System\TSConfig.exe`

I have VS 2010 (Shell), VS 2012 and VS2013 installed.

I have also added this user in the administrator group on that server. I have restarted the build server multiple times. I am not sure what else to try. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

Be ensure that the BuildService is not running with a local account such as "NT_AUTHORITY\Network Service". If so, please change it with a domain account and add the user account to the administrator group. Restart TFS build server machine, and re-queue the build.

In addition, please also have a check on this blog for the details on how to work with Installshield with TFS build:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishp/archive/2014/03/04/installshield-and-team-build-on-tfs.aspx

Comment: This works for vNext as well. The reboot step is important!